# How to use an icon from Android's Drawables as a notification icon?

Tags: android, notifications

[Android Drawables](http://androiddrawables.com/) is a site that lists a lot of built-in icons available for Android.

If I wanted to use one of them, for example [`emo_im_angel`](http://androiddrawables.com/Emoticons.html), as a notification icon, how might I do it?

For example:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(XXX)
        .setContentTitle("My notification")
        .setContentText("Hello World!");
```

What goes in place of `XXX` to use `emo_im_angel` and what do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

All android drawables are available under `android.R.drawable.<name>`

Though, I'm not sure if emoticons are placed there or publicly available from other code.

Source code here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/com/android/internal/widget/Smileys.java

Answer (score 0):

Download the icon copy it in drawable folder and then put this code "R.drawable.imagename" Instead of imagename u need to put in ur case emo_im_angel.

Comment: But these are supposed to be *built-in*. I still have to have a separate copy?